# algorithmicx package comments on a single line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, algorithmicx

Is it possible in `algorithmicx` package to have comments not aligned to the right side?

For example I have code like this -

```
\begin{algorithm}[!ht]
\caption{My Algo.}
\label{myalgo}
\begin{algorithmic}

\State $\epsilon$ = 1.0;

\Comment{Explore Latency Dimension}
\While {explorationTime <= timeLimit}
    \State $\epsilon$ = $\epsilon$ / 2;
    \State calculateIncrements($\epsilon$);

    \Comment{Explore L dimension}

    \While {lQuery <= lUpperLimit}
         \State Query (0, Query, bQuery, pQuery);
         \If {result = WORKING}
             \State mark points 
             \Comment{no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here.}
             \State Break
         \Else
             \If {result = NOT WORKING}
                \State mark from 0 to lQuery as NOT WORKING.
             \EndIf
         \EndIf

         \State lQuery += lEpsIncr;
    \EndWhile
\EndWhile

\State $calcPoints()$

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

So what is happening is that, the package everytime aligns the comments to the right side. But for this comment `\Comment{no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here.}`, I would like it to have it on single line rather than multiple lines and aligned to right. It becomes a little confusing for me.

Is it possible that we can have comments like -

```
> no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here.
Break
```

It should be aligned at the indentation level of the statements.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Modifying the comment macro is possible using `\algrenewcomment`, like

```
\algrenewcomment[1]{\(\triangleright\) #1}
```

The original `\Comment` command inserted an `\hfill`, which I've removed above. This would replace the existing `\Comment` command globally. However, you can also define your own (new) `\LineComment` command,

```
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}
```

and intermix it with the regular `\Comment`, like I did below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!ht]
  \caption{My Algo.}\label{myalgo}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State $\epsilon$ = 1.0; \Comment{Explore Latency Dimension}
    \While {explorationTime $\leq$ timeLimit}
      \State $\epsilon = \epsilon / 2$;
      \State calculateIncrements($\epsilon$);
      \LineComment{Explore L dimension}
      \While {lQuery $\leq$ lUpperLimit}
        \State Query (0, Query, bQuery, pQuery);
        \If {result = WORKING}
          \State mark points 
          \LineComment{no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here.}
          \State Break
        \Else
          \If {result = NOT WORKING}
            \State mark from 0 to lQuery as NOT WORKING.
          \EndIf
        \EndIf
        \State lQuery += lEpsIncr;
      \EndWhile
    \EndWhile
    \State calcPoints()
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect ! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: This does not respect indentation

Comment: @sumneuron Can you elaborate on the type of indentation that is ignored?

Comment: @Werner the start of the comment is indented correctly. However, if the comment is long, the subsequent lines take up the full line width of its containing element.

Comment: Using `\Statex` instead of `\State` in the `\LineComment` macro prevents the line comment from receiving its own line number.

Comment: However, this flushes the comment to the left. Check https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184829/25523 for a solution to this issue.