# Align pseudocode comments to the left

Tags: indentation, algorithmicx, pseudocode

Writing comments in pseudocode, I wanted to insert comments which are not aligned to the right side of the line which is commented. [This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74880/algorithmicx-package-comments-on-a-single-line) helped me a lot.

However, I want comments to stand above the code line to which they refer and be always left-aligned.

Reason: If the comment refers to an elsif, then the comment is inside the previous if-block. Thus, it is indented. I don't want it to be indented, I want it to be at the same horizontal position as the corresponding line is.

Starting with this

```
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}
```

How can I design it to be aligned corresponding to the next line (which is left-aligned in 90% of the cases)?

I am using this:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}\parindent0mm
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}
```

Also, I want to define a new command, not redefine an existing one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try inserting `\hfill`

```
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State  \(\triangleright\) #1 \hfill~}
```

Comment: This keeps the triangle where it is and moves the actual comment to the right end of the line..

Comment: I just noticed that the problem description is not quite accurate: My comments are supposed to be left aligned, sorry. I updated the description

Comment: put the `\hfill` before the triangle, then the `\State` should be left and the comment right aligned. See my edit

Comment: this pushes the comment to the right, not to the left

Comment: see edit, but I need a _complete_ example to see what you resally want

Comment: This adds a line number for the `\LineComment`