# Properly indent comments with no line-numbering in algorithmicx

Tags: indentation, line-numbering, comments, algorithmicx

Writing comments in pseudocode, I wanted to insert comments to the right side of the line which is commented. [This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74880/algorithmicx-package-comments-on-a-single-line) help me a lot.

The algorithm is line-numbered, however I need the comments with no number! (as a regular `\comment` command do), but because the macro has the `\State` command in it, it really is a normal line with number.

```
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. You can also indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192), or you can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5):

The following definition of `\LineComment` provides the appropriate indentation *without* numbering the line:

```
\makeatletter
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm \(\triangleright\) #1}
\makeatother
```

`\Statex` sets an `\item[]` (note that the algorithm is actually a list, so `\item[]` sets an empty item and therefore has no line number), while `\ALG@thistlm` contains the appropriate indentation of the current list item.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\makeatletter
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm \(\triangleright\) #1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!ht]
  \caption{My Algo.}\label{myalgo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $\epsilon$ = 1.0; \Comment{Explore Latency Dimension}
    \While {explorationTime $\leq$ timeLimit}
      \State $\epsilon = \epsilon / 2$;
      \State calculateIncrements($\epsilon$);
      \LineComment{Explore L dimension}
      \While {lQuery $\leq$ lUpperLimit}
        \State Query (0, Query, bQuery, pQuery);
        \If {result = WORKING}
          \State mark points 
          \LineComment{no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here.}
          \State Break
        \Else
          \If {result = NOT WORKING}
            \State mark from 0 to lQuery as NOT WORKING.
          \EndIf
        \EndIf
        \State lQuery += lEpsIncr;
      \EndWhile
    \EndWhile
    \State calcPoints()
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work if you make a `\LineComment` just after a function start with `\Function`

Comment: @RasmusWL, for comments right after a function start where an extra indentation is needed, I had success with `\algnewcommand{\IndentLineComment}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@tlm \(\triangleright\) #1}`.