# How to indent long comment continuation in the algorithmicx pseudocode

Tags: indentation, width, algorithmicx

In the MWE, I try to add line continuation indent to the answer given in [Properly indent comments with no line-numbering in algorithmicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153120/properly-indent-comments-with-no-line-numbering-in-algorithmicx)

E.g. I am trying to write the `\LineCommentCont` .

I am using the `linegoal`package to set the width parameter of the `\parbox`automatically, and `\hangindent` to indent the continuation.

I have two problems: 1) `\linegoal` seems to return a little less space than what is available. 2) How should I assign right `\hangindent` amount?

Alternatively, you can supply an answer with a totally different approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\usepackage{linegoal}

\makeatletter
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm \(\triangleright\) #1}
\algnewcommand{\LineCommentCont}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1 $\triangleright$ #1}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!ht]
  \caption{My Algo.}\label{myalgo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $\epsilon$ = 1.0; \Comment{Explore Latency Dimension}
    \While {explorationTime $\leq$ timeLimit}
      \State $\epsilon = \epsilon / 2$;
      \State calculateIncrements($\epsilon$);
      \LineComment{Explore L dimension}
      \While {lQuery $\leq$ lUpperLimit}
        \State Query (0, Query, bQuery, pQuery);
        \If {result = WORKING}
          \State mark points 
          \LineComment{no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here. no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here. no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here. }
          \LineCommentCont{no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here. no  to explore more. we just want to stop over here. no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here. }
          \State Break
        \Else
          \If {result = NOT WORKING}
            \State mark from 0 to lQuery as NOT WORKING.
          \EndIf
        \EndIf
        \State lQuery += lEpsIncr;
      \EndWhile
    \EndWhile
    \State calcPoints()
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: Comment line continuation in algorithmicx]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following definition of `\LineCommentCont`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\makeatletter
\newlength{\trianglerightwidth}
\settowidth{\trianglerightwidth}{$\triangleright$~}
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm $\triangleright$ #1}
\algnewcommand{\LineCommentCont}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{\hangindent=\trianglerightwidth \hangafter=1 \strut$\triangleright$ #1\strut}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!ht]
  \caption{My Algo.}\label{myalgo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $\epsilon$ = 1.0; \Comment{Explore Latency Dimension}
    \While {explorationTime $\leq$ timeLimit}
      \State $\epsilon = \epsilon / 2$;
      \State calculateIncrements($\epsilon$);
      \LineComment{Explore L dimension}
      \While {lQuery $\leq$ lUpperLimit}
        \State Query (0, Query, bQuery, pQuery);
        \If {result = WORKING}
          \State mark points 
          \LineComment{no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here. no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here. no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here. }
          \LineCommentCont{no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here. no  to explore more. we just want to stop over here. no need to explore more. we just want to stop over here.}
          \State Break
        \Else
          \If {result = NOT WORKING}
            \State mark from 0 to lQuery as NOT WORKING.
          \EndIf
        \EndIf
        \State lQuery += lEpsIncr;
      \EndWhile
    \EndWhile
    \State calcPoints()
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Since you're indenting the "list" (algorithm) by `\ALG@thistlm` you only need to subtract that from `\linewidth` in order to have the correct width of you `\parbox`. There is therefore no need to use [`linegoal`](http://ctan.org/pkg/linegoal) to determine the remaining width of the line.

The width `\trianglerightwidth` is obtained by measuring the width of `$\trianglewidth$~`.

I've added some `\strut`s to the macros to avoid line height problems when you don't have descenders in your comment.

---

The indentation at every level is incremented by `\algorithmicindent` (default is `1.5em`). Using

```
\algnewcommand{\LineCommentCont}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{\hangindent=\algorithmicindent \hangafter=1 \strut\makebox[\algorithmicindent][l]{$\triangleright$}#1\strut}}
```

inserts an equivalently-spaced indentation to what you see with the other constructions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. but I actually wanted the continuation indent to be same as the other indents in the picture. I mean the indent of the content inside while. I think, around two times `trianglerightwidth`. May be you know that value?

Comment: @ozi: I've added an updated that uses the default `\algorithmicindent` for your `\hangindent`, as well as the width of the `\triangleright` marker. I assume this is what you were after?

Comment: More than what I want :). I used this: `\algnewcommand{\LineCommentCont}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{\hangindent=\algorithmicindent \hangafter=1 $\triangleright${} #1\strut}}`.

Comment: I noticed a problem: if the comment is not after 'mark points' but right after `if result = `, it is indented one less then necessary.

Comment: @ozi Since I personally don't mind about numbering line comments, I replaced `Statex` by `State`, and removed `\hskip\ALG@thistlm` as well, which gives me the correct behaviour for both "just after a \If" and "After an existing \State". There is the code I use: `\algnewcommand{\LineCommentCont}[1]{\State \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{\hangindent=\trianglerightwidth \hangafter=1 \strut$\triangleright$ #1\strut}}`

Comment: The definition is fragile :( . I am able to use this MWE, but these definitions in another document break with 'Undefined control sequence'. I tried removing all usepackage definitions and it still happens. Perhaps it is because I am definiting a 'switch' environment as well.

Comment: @malaverdiere: Post some code so one can look at it...

Answer (score 0):

What about simply

```
\algnewcommand{\LineCommentCont}[1]{\State \phantom{$\triangleright$} #1}
```