# How to have continuation indent in algorithmicx algorithm for long comments and States

Tags: algorithmicx

Assuming that I can apply the same solution to my document, previously I asked [how to have continuation indent in line comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169598/how-to-indent-long-comment-continuation-in-the-algorithmicx-pseudocode) on somebody else's MWE and got an answer.

However, I could not apply that solution to MY document. So I am re-posting a MWE with keeping my preamble, with following questions:

1-) How to have continuation indent in the line comment below?

2-) While you are at it, can you add continuation indent to the long `\State`, too?

```
% page layout ------------------------
\documentclass[]{article}
%\usepackage[paperheight=22.9cm, paperwidth=8.1cm, margin=0.1cm]{geometry}

% preamble ---------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./}{./fig/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.svg}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand{\fixme}[1]{\todo[inline]{#1}}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\date{}



\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}


\begin{document}




\newcommand{\To}{\textbf{to\ }}
\newcommand{\Step}{\textbf{step\ }}
\newcommand{\Gets}{$ \gets\ $}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
\floatname{algorithm}{Pseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\trianglerightwidth}
\settowidth{\trianglerightwidth}{$\triangleright$~}
\algnewcommand{\LineCommentCont}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{\hangindent=\trianglerightwidth \hangafter=1 \strut$\triangleright$ #1\strut}}
\makeatother



\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\Procedure{Compare}{P,A,I,E}

\ForAll{$p \in P$}
    \ForAll{$a \in A$}
        \For{$i$ \Gets $1$ \To $I$ \Step 1}
            \LineCommentCont Run the algorithm $a$ on problem $p$ to get list of (function evaluation, corresponding global best solution value) pairs $Y$. Algorithm $a$ terminates after doing $E$ function evaluations.

            \State $Y_i$ \Gets $a(p,E)$ aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc 
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{T }
\label{alg:compare}
\end{algorithm}



\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key problem was that there was a necessity to use comment as a parameter to `\LineCommentCont`, instead of `\LineCommentRun Run the...` which took only the first letter we must write `\LineCommentRun{Run the...}`. I created a new command named `\MyState` to handle multiline state situations. I enclose an example and a preview of the result.

```
%! *latex mal-algorithm.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\newcommand{\To}{\textbf{to\ }}
\newcommand{\Step}{\textbf{step\ }}
\newcommand{\Gets}{$ \gets\ $}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
\floatname{algorithm}{Pseudocode}
\makeatletter
% First new command...
\newlength{\trianglerightwidth}
\settowidth{\trianglerightwidth}{$\triangleright$~}
\algnewcommand{\LineCommentCont}[1]{\Statex \hskip\ALG@thistlm%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}
{\leftskip=\algorithmicindent
  \hangindent=\algorithmicindent 
  \hangafter=1%
  \strut\makebox[\algorithmicindent][c]{$\triangleright$}#1\strut}
  } % \trianglerightwidth
% Second new command...
\algnewcommand{\MyState}[1]{\State
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{\hangindent=\algorithmicindent\strut\hangafter=1#1\strut}}
\makeatother
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Compare}{P,A,I,E}
\ForAll{$p \in P$}
    \ForAll{$a \in A$}
        \For{$i$ \Gets $1$ \To $I$ \Step 1}
            \LineCommentCont{Run the algorithm $a$ on problem $p$ to get list of (function evaluation, corresponding global best solution value) pairs $Y$. Algorithm $a$ terminates after doing $E$ function evaluations.}
            \MyState{$Y_i$ \Gets $a(p,E)$ aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc aaaa bbbb ccccc}
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{My first algorithm}
\label{alg:compare}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Shoot! The curly braces! Thanks. But, 1) there is still a problem: `\hskip\ALG@thistlm` gives nice indent to the first line of the comment inside the `for each a in A` loop, but it does not inside `for $i \gets 1 to...`, as evident in your preview. 2) Also please add a `\hangindent=\algorithmicindent` into your `\MyState`definition, so that continuation lines also have indent.

Comment: To 1) I believe it should be this way as that comment is a (unnumbered) part of the fourth line. I am trying something new. To 2) I will take a look at it. ... Is it better? See the update.

Comment: For 1) I see... But my intention is different: It is not a part of the fourth line. It is an explanation for the fifth line, as programmers do. So, its beginning indent should be same as the beginning of fifth line. Plus you should make `\hangindent=\algorithmicindent`, not zero. A little more complexity arises from this: if I put it after `end for` it puts to where I want. So, inconsistent behavior. May be we should add a long comment and a long state between each `for each` and each `end for` 2) Nice.

Comment: Well, I tried that, but when the triangle started as the fifth line, it didn't look right. See my next experiment.

Comment: There is another potential solution. Prepare pseudocode with minimum of notes and add notes and comments below the pseudocode with reference to the line number.

Comment: Sure :). But I want this to be in my arsenal. Continuing with your example, triangle starts a little after it should isn't it? It should start where `$Y_i`starts. Everything else is fine.

Comment: There was too much empty space after the triangle and before other text, this is probably the best we can get. The space now represents regular space between two words.