# how to left justify comments to indent same as other text in Algorithmic

Tags: horizontal-alignment, comments, algorithmicx

[image]

How do I left justify my comments in the algorithm.

I am using `algorithmicx` package.

What I want is: to pull the comment to left as shown in the attached snapshot.

The code for my algorithm is

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm} \label{algoQ}
    \caption{Algorithm to check quality of methods}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \For{\textbf{each} $msd$ in$msdList$}  \Comment { \% for each MSD \%}
    \Statex   \Comment { \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
    \EndFor \textbf{endFor}
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your own `\LeftComment` that doesn't insert the default `\hfill`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\LeftComment}[1]{\Statex \(\triangleright\) #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm to check quality of methods}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \For{\textbf{each} msd $\in$ msdList}  \Comment { \% for each MSD \%}
      \Statex \Comment { \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
      \LeftComment { \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is a modified version of `\LeftComment` that has a starred version. The starred version prints a flush-left comment, while the default (unstarred) version sets it flush-left at the indentation level of the current group:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\LeftComment}{s m}{%
  \Statex \IfBooleanF{#1}{\hspace*{\ALG@thistlm}}\(\triangleright\) #2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm to check quality of methods}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \For{\textbf{each} msd $\in$ msdList}  \Comment { \% for each MSD \%}
      \Statex \Comment { \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
      \LeftComment { \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
      \LeftComment*{ \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
      \For{\textbf{each} msd $\in$ msdList}  \Comment { \% for each MSD \%}
        \Statex \Comment { \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
        \LeftComment { \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
        \LeftComment*{ \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
      \EndFor
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ,.. this works... but if I have one more nesting of for loop .. how do I indent my comment to that ...

Comment: @Subu: See the updated answer that now provides `\LeftComment` and `\LeftComment*`.

Comment: yes the updated answer works fine ...

Answer (score 5):

This is an alternative for the nested loop issue. Since the default algorithmic indent is 1.5em. A new dimension `algindent` is set to 1.5em, so that it can be multiplied, and a command `\LeftComment{#1}{#2}` takes two inputs: #1=number of nested indentation, #2=text for comments, shown below

```
\algnewcommand\LeftComment[2]{%
\hspace{#1\algindent}$\triangleright$ \eqparbox{COMMENT}{#2} \hfill %
}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newdimen{\algindent}
\setlength\algindent{1.5em}          % algorithmic indent=1.5em
\algnewcommand\LeftComment[2]{%
\hspace{#1\algindent}$\triangleright$ \eqparbox{COMMENT}{#2} \hfill %
}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm} \label{algoQ}
\caption{Algorithm to check quality of methods}
\begin{algorithmic}
\For{\textbf{each} $msd$ in$msdList$} 
\Statex   \LeftComment{1} { \% first for loop service \%}
\For{\textbf{each} $msd$ in$msdList$}  \Comment { \% for each MSD \%}
\Statex   \LeftComment{2} { \% second nested for loop service\%}
\For{\textbf{each} $msd$ in$msdList$}  \Comment { \% for each MSD \%}
\Statex   \LeftComment{2} { \% third nested for loop service\%}
\EndFor \textbf{endFor}
\Statex   \LeftComment{2} { \% second nested for loop service\%}
\EndFor \textbf{endFor}
\Statex   \LeftComment{1} { \% first for loop service\%}
\EndFor \textbf{endFor}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```