# Justifying code according to corresponding elements indentation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithms

How do I justify my comments as to inner for loop indentation in the below code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm} \label{algoQ}
\caption{Algorithm to check quality of methods}
\begin{algorithmic}
\For{\textbf{each} $methods$ in$methodList$}
\For{\textbf{each} $msd$ in$msdList$}  \Comment { \% for each MSD \%}
\Statex   \Comment { \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}
\EndFor \textbf{endFor}
\EndFor \textbf{endFor}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: updated post for clarity

Comment: This was part of [your comment in a previous post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184827/how-to-left-justify-comments-to-indent-same-as-other-text-in-algorithmic/184829?noredirect=1#comment427259_184829), which has been answered there already.

Comment: Oh yes sorry Werner, Subu please don't re-ask the same question

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, do you mean like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm} \label{algoQ}
\caption{Algorithm to check quality of methods}
\begin{algorithmic}
\For{\textbf{each} $methods$ in$methodList$}
\For{\textbf{each} $msd$ in$msdList$}  
          \Comment {\makebox[6.4cm][l]{ \% for each MSD \%}}
\Statex   \Comment {\makebox[6.4cm][l]{ \% get MSDs referenced method service \%}}
\EndFor \textbf{endFor}
\EndFor \textbf{endFor}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```